# Blank space above first row in table view ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I have `ViewController` and `tableView` in it. When I add elements in `tableView` blank space above first column appears. I tried to select it, but only columns below that space are selected. I have tried to log `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method and it is called 13 times, but I have only 12 elements in list. In `size inspector` of `tableView`  `Scroll View Size` params are all 0. `Delegate` and `data source` are connected to `ViewController`. Any idea why it is blank?

in iOS7 table items can go over that space when you scroll down, and on prior versions that space is fixed and blank(can't be replaced with table view items).

**EDIT:** 
[image]

Comment: Are u using a navigation controller?

Comment: I am pushing view controller with table view in it(not tableViewController), without using navigation controller on view that is pushed.

Comment: Try AutoLayout option

Comment: I want to develop for 5.0 iOS version, so I can't use autolayout.

Comment: @lugonja please add the screen short for better understanding..

Comment: I already added screen shoot in my edit of post.

Comment: By the looks of things it is setting a view for the header what happens when you adding `-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section { return [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]; }` Assuming you aren't already returning something here - if you are please share this.

Comment: check or log `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` method of your tableviewdatasource

Answer (score -1):

try to use self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone; in your ViewController. It helped me.

Comment: Didn't helped me. Do you have TableViewController or ViewController?

Comment: I have ViewController and create UITableView in code not in storyboard. Does your ViewController.view have others subviews except UITableView ? And this problem only with iOS7?

Comment: in iOS7 space can be replaced with table when you scroll down, and on prior versions that space is fixed and blank(can't be replaced with table view items).